# R - Passing data frame to function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

R beginner here. I'm trying to write a function on my own which has a data frame as an argument and then reorders the data frame and then uses ggplot. I've been struggling with trying to get the function to work and somehow I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

The first code I had was this,

```
pareto_plot <- function(pareto_data, title, x_label, y_label, filename){
pareto_calc = pareto_data[order(-pareto_data[2]),]
colnames(pareto_calc) = c("sku", "volume")

pareto_calc$sku_perc = 1/length(pareto_calc$sku)
pareto_calc$sku_cum = cumsum(pareto_calc$sku_perc)

pareto_calc$vol_perc = pareto_calc$volume/sum(pareto_calc$volume)
pareto_calc$vol_cum = cumsum(pareto_calc$vol_perc)

ggplot(pareto_calc, aes(x=pareto_data$sku_cum, y=pareto_data$vol_cum)) +   geom_line(col="blue") + 
geom_line(y=0.8, col="red") +geom_line(x=0.2, col="red") + 
ggtitle(title) + ylab(y_label) + xlab(x_label)

ggsave(paste(filename,".png", sep=""))
}
```

When I used the above code, I got an error,

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'pareto_calc' not found
```

I then changed the code to make use of `data` as i saw that a lot of examples online made use of it as an argument. My modified code was now,

```
pareto_plot <- function(data, title, x_label, y_label, filename){
pareto_data = data

pareto_data[order(-pareto_data[2]),]
colnames(pareto_data) = c("sku", "volume")

pareto_data$sku_perc = 1/length(pareto_data$sku)
pareto_data$sku_cum = cumsum(pareto_data$sku_perc)

pareto_data$vol_perc = pareto_data$volume/sum(pareto_data$volume)
pareto_data$vol_cum = cumsum(pareto_data$vol_perc)

ggplot(pareto_data, aes(x=pareto_data$sku_cum, y=pareto_data$vol_cum)) +   geom_line(col="blue") + 
geom_line(y=0.8, col="red") +geom_line(x=0.2, col="red") + 
ggtitle(title) + ylab(y_label) + xlab(x_label)

ggsave(paste(filename,".png", sep=""))
}
```

With this code, I now get the error,

```
Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Insert `browser()` at the beginning of your function and run (by hand) each line. See where it goes wrong and examine the objects involved in the operation.

Comment: It's better not to use `data` as a name of variable because there is function `data()` in base package `utils`. Let it be `data1` or `mydata`

Comment: Have a look at this page: [Debugging with RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio). Learning to debug is essential and you'll save yourself a lot of time by learning how to do it properly.

Comment: Thanks guys. The debugging link helped. Should've checked that out earlier. Will report back with what I get.

Comment: @inscaven this is a **very** minor quibble--many well-written functions use an argument called "data", e.g., `lm`, `ggplot`. Worrying about creating non-function objects with the name of functions (especially internal to the scope of a function) only makes sense if there's potential for ambiguity. When a function takes a `data` argument, it's usually clear what the intent is.

Comment: Speaking of which, @yohanf: don't use `$` inside `aes()`. ggplot has a `data` argument that you've used, specifying the data frame again is asking for trouble--especially if you facet or do any summary stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a function, it is often easiest to write the code first, without making it a function, until you are sure it works. Then wrap it as a function.

```
set.seed(33)

df <- data.frame(V1 = runif(10),
                 V2 = rnorm(10))

pareto_plot <- function(data, title, x_label, y_label, filename){
        pareto_data <- data[order(-data[2]),] #you forgot to assign it

        names(pareto_data)  <-  c("sku", "volume")

        pareto_data$sku_perc  <-  1/length(pareto_data$sku)
        pareto_data$sku_cum <- cumsum(pareto_data$sku_perc)

        pareto_data$vol_perc <- pareto_data$volume/sum(pareto_data$volume)
        pareto_data$vol_cum <- cumsum(pareto_data$vol_perc)

        ggplot(pareto_data, aes(x=sku_cum, y=vol_cum)) +   geom_line(color="blue") + 
                geom_line(y=0.8, col="red") +geom_line(x=0.2, col="red") + 
                ggtitle(title) + ylab(y_label) + xlab(x_label)

        ggsave(paste(filename,".png", sep=""))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guy! Debugging really helped. Adding the x and y variables for `aes` without the dataframe name and `$` helped.